# After using the train data, I can't predict target value "net quantity" in the test data because they are all given as nan values, what should I do?

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, forecasting, training-data

I need to implement an ML model to accurately predict the sales quantities
called "net_quantity". According to given data the model should work for each unique product code and generate predictions for period_id = 1 for which net_quantity is "NaN".

However, after using the train data, I can't predict target value "net quantity" in the test data because they are all given as nan values. But isn't that the logic of building a prediction model, estimating the unknown, using factors. Please helpp

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("raw-data.csv")
#Splitting data to train and test
df_train = data.dropna(subset=['net_quantity'])
df_test = data[data['net_quantity'].isna()]
#Training model
model = LinearRegression() 
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
#Test model
predictions = model.predict(test_data)  # Forecasts
```

Here When I want to continue and build the model, it gives me an error because the "net quantity" column in test_data consists of nan values.

Comment: What are `X_train` and `y_train`? You use them without defining them.

Answer (score 2):

According to your statement, the target variable is 'net_quantity'. But while defining df_test, you are setting the data to have all those values from the data that have null values for 'net quantity' variable.
This causes the test set to have null values, hence you are getting such results. Folowing should be done to get desired results.

Here is the sample code for task on hand:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3], "B": [2, 3, 1, 0, 9, 2, 1, 4], "net_quantity": [1, 0, 3, -3, -3, np.nan, 2, np.nan]})


    A   B   net_quantity
0   1   2    1.0
1   2   3    0.0
2   3   1    3.0
3   2   0   -3.0
4   1   9   -3.0
5   3   2    NaN
6   1   1    2.0
7   3   4    NaN

# Remove rows with missing values in 'net_quantity' column
df = df.dropna(subset=['net_quantity'])


    A   B   net_quantity
0   1   2    1.0
1   2   3    0.0
2   3   1    3.0
3   2   0   -3.0
4   1   9   -3.0
6   1   1    2.0

# Separate the features (X) and the target variable (y)
X = df.drop(['net_quantity'], axis=1)
y = df['net_quantity']

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8)

# Create and train a linear regression model
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict the target variable for the test set
y_preds = model.predict(X_test)
```

This way you will get your desired output.
Hope it helps!